# managementObject and different null warnings

Tags: c#, reference, null, .net-6.0

I have the following code in .net 6 and VS 2022. To hold it easy I comment the warning behind the line. I don't know how to fix this. Hope someone can help me.

```
try
{
    var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
    using (ManagementObjectCollection managementObjectCollection = searcher.Get())
    {
        ManagementObject? managementObject = managementObjectCollection.OfType<ManagementObject>().FirstOrDefault();
        hardwareComputerName = managementObject["name"].ToString().ToLower(); // 'managementObject' may be null here. CS8602 Dereference of a possibly null reference. (2x)
        hardwareComputerManufacturer = managementObject["Manufacturer"].ToString(); // 'managementObject' is not null here. CS8601 Possible null reference assignment.
        hardwareComputerModel = managementObject["model"].ToString(); // 'managementObject' is not null here. CS8601 Possible null reference assignment.
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Problem im Abschnitt Name, Hersteller und Modell.");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`managementObject` may be `null` (it's nullable and `FirstOrDefault` may return `null`) and, on the line subsequent to its declaration, you access a member of `managementObject` without first verifying it is not null which may result in a null reference exception, hence the warning.

You have several options, two being

1. replace `FirstOrDefault` with `First`; will throw if no element found but the result is never `null`
2. test for null and only execute the member access statements if it's not null

   ManagementObject? managementObject = ...FirstOrDefault();

   if( null != managementObject )
   {
   ...
   }

Comment: Thanks for your anweser, but point 2 didn't work. The warnings are still there. I think youe code is clear and I tested some methods. Nevertheless I think I do it wrong. Can you edit please your post with my code-example above, so that I see what's my fault?

Comment: @TheQuestionmark my guess is managementObject[“…”] can return null and the vars on the left side of the assignment are not nullable.  Make them nullable or set them with a default value via null coalesce operator

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, that given't the warnings. Thanks to Moho for the help.

```
try
{
    var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
    using (ManagementObjectCollection managementObjectCollection = searcher.Get())
    {
        ManagementObject? managementObject = managementObjectCollection.OfType<ManagementObject>().First();
        hardwareComputerName = managementObject["name"].ToString()?.ToLower() ?? "Default";
        hardwareComputerManufacturer = managementObject["Manufacturer"].ToString() ?? "Default";
        hardwareComputerModel = managementObject["model"].ToString() ?? "Default";
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Problem im Abschnitt Name, Hersteller und Modell.");
}
```